# NullPointerException when dialog positive button onClick calls interface

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I'm trying to use an interface to send a click event from the AlertDialog.Builder.setPositiveButton's onClick event.

Please help me out. I've been looking all over for a similar problem to use for guidance.

The NPE is at this line:

```
     mListener.onSetBalanceDialogPositiveClick(SetBalanceDialog.this);
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at com.smb.allowance.SetBalanceDialog$2.onClick(SetBalanceDialog.java:75)
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
08-19 20:05:50.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5795):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the Dialog code:

```
package com.smb.allowance;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SetBalanceDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener {

    private EditText editTextSetBalance;
    private static double dInput = 0;

    public interface SetBalanceDialogListener{
        public void onSetBalanceDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    } // end interface

    SetBalanceDialogListener mListener;

    public void onAttache(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mListener = (SetBalanceDialogListener) activity;
        }catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement SetBalanceDialogListener");
            }
    } // end onAttach

    public SetBalanceDialog(){
        // default empty constructor
    }// end constructor

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_balance_set, null);       

        editTextSetBalance = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextSetBalance);

        editTextSetBalance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!editTextIsEmpty(editTextSetBalance)){
                        editTextSetBalance.setText("");
                    }

                    clearEditText(editTextSetBalance);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(view)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setMessage(R.string.set_begin_balance)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mListener.onSetBalanceDialogPositiveClick(SetBalanceDialog.this);
            }
        });

        // show soft keyboard automatically 
        editTextSetBalance.requestFocus();
        editTextSetBalance.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

        return builder.create();

    } // end onCreateDialog
```

The Activity that implements the interface:

```
package com.smb.allowance;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.smb.allowance.ResetBalanceDialogFragment.ResetBalanceDialogListener;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
                implements ResetBalanceDialogListener,        SetBalanceDialog.SetBalanceDialogListener {

@Override
public void onSetBalanceDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // For testing functionality
      onReset();
}
```

Is it possible that how I am handling/mishandling the EditText view is causing this NPE?

I'm new to android/java and programming in general, thanks for any help.

Comment: Where are you `implementing` that interface ?

Comment: I've added the portions of the activity that implement the interface to my question.

Comment: You have the answer :) Infact two answers posted at exactly the same time telling you the same thing :) Take your pick and accept one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mListener is null

It is null because you never assign it to anything! (Oh yes I do I hear you think!) But you don't

You have an `public void`onAttache(Activity activity)` method which will never be called because it should be

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
```

You should also add an @Override for inherited methods and call super. This will make sure you get a compilation error if you get the method declaration wrong as well as ensuring that any code in the base class inherited method gets run. Even if that method is empty in the version of the SDK you are using it doesn't mean it won't be empty at some unkown point in the future.

Comment: Yes, thank you! well that is embarrassing. But thanks for the lesson in proof reading.

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling for overridden methods:

```
public void onAttache(Activity activity)
```

should be

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
```

and it is also a good practice to check listeners for `null` before calling them.

Comment: Thanks for the the advice. I will implement checks from now on.